# Reading an image from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, image, swift, save, nsuserdefaults

I have a swift app in which I have to save an image for a profile picture. I have saved it with the NSUserDefaults code below:

```
defaults.setObject(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image), forKey: "ProfilePicture")
```

My only question now is how do I read this from a file and then apply it to an UIImageView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIImagePNGRepresentation` creates an NSData version of the image. So when you extract it from user defaults, you will evidently need to turn an NSData into an image — which you can do quite simply, with `UIImage(data:)`.

[I am also trying to resist the temptation to advise you not to put some huge blob of data like an image into NSUserDefaults - use the Application Support folder instead. But I'm not succeeding!]

Comment: I'm with Matt. NSUserDefaults is for small bits of data, not big things like images. Store the image in  the Application Support folder, documents, or some other app folder, and store a path to it in user defaults.